# Click on row to open modal dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to work out how I can make my dataTable rows clickable to open a Bootstrap Modal to edit the clicked row. I currently have a "View" button that opens a modal but I would also like to be able to just click a row.

Based on the code below, what do I need to add to pass the "RecordID" to a modal.

```
tabletoday = $('#userTable').DataTable({
    createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        $('td:eq(0)', row).css('padding-left', '2px');
        $('td:eq(3)', row).css('padding-right', '2px');
    },
    autoWidth: false,
    order: [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "asc"]
    ],
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    bInfo: false,
    scrollY: "550px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'get_conf_bookings.php',
        dataSrc: '',
    },
    language: {
        "emptyTable": "There are no rooms booked for <?php echo $date; ?>"
    },
    columnDefs: [{
            "targets": [5, 6, 7, 8],
            "orderable": false
        },
        {
            targets: [1],
            className: 'zoom'
        },
        {
            "targets": [5, 6, 7],
            "className": "text-center"
        },
    ],
    columns: [{
            data: "RoomName",
            width: '13%'
        },
        {
            data: "ClientImage",
            width: '10%',
            render: function (data, type) {
                if (data != null) {
                    return '<img src="' + imagepathroom + '' + data + '" class="WayfinderSignageImage" />';
                } else {
                    return '<img src="' + noimageroom + '" class="WayfinderSignageImage"/>';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            data: "ClientName",
            width: '38%'
        },
        {
            data: "RoomFromDate",
            width: '12%'
        },
        {
            data: "RoomToDate",
            width: '11%'
        },

        {
            data: 'Override',
            width: '6%',
            render: function (data, type) {
                if (data == 2) {
                    return '<img src="' + pendingroomoverride + '" class="wayfinder-on"/>';
                } else if (data == 1) {
                    return '<img src="' + onimageroomoverride + '" class="wayfinder-on"/>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'WayfinderOnOff',
            width: '6%',
            render: function (data, type) {
                if (data == 1 || data == 0) {
                    return '<img src="' + offimageroom + '" class="wayfinder-on"/>';
                } else {
                    return '<img src="' + onimageroom + '" class="wayfinder-off"/>';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'RecordID',
            width: '4%',
            render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var recordid = full.RecordID;
                return '<input type="button" name="edit" value="View" data-id=' + recordid + ' class="btn btn-conf-view btn-xs edit_data_modal">'
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'ToDateTime',
            "visible": false
        },
    ],
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {
        $('td', row).attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
        if (data.ToDateTime < nowtimestamp) {
            $(row).removeClass('userTableCol0GrayLeft').addClass('userTableCol0RedLeft');
        } else {
            $(row).removeClass('userTableCol0RedLeft').addClass('userTableCol0GrayLeft');
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables supports DOM click events on its tables - so you can do something like this:

```
  tabletoday = $('#userTable').DataTable({
     ...
  });

  // follows after the end of your DataTable definition:
  $('#userTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = tabletoday.row( this ).data();
      alert( 'Record ID: ' + data.RecordID );
  } );
```

That gives you the record ID you need to pass to your modal.

More details about these "delegated events" can be found [here](https://datatables.net/manual/events#Bubbling).

**UPDATE**

My initial solution was to use this:

```
alert( 'Record ID: ' + data[7] );
```

That was based on the incorrect assumption that each row of data was structured as an array of values - so, something approximately like this:

```
  [ 
    "Brindley Suite", 
    "navex_logo.png",
    "NaveX Systems",
    null,
    "0",
    "03-08-2020 07:00",
    "08-08-2020 18:00",
    "53325",
    1596909600, 
    "1"
  ]
```

In the above case, we can access a value using its index in the array: `data[7]`

However, in this case, each row is an object (containing key/value pairs) more like this:

```
  { 
    "RoomName": "Brindley Suite", 
    "ClientImage": "navex_logo.png",
    "ClientName": "NaveX Systems",
    "FullBoardRoom": null,
    "Override": "0",
    "RoomFromDate": "03-08-2020 07:00",
    "RoomToDate": "08-08-2020 18:00",
    "RecordID": "53325",
    "ToDateTime": 1596909600, 
    "WayfinderOnOff": "1"
  }
```

In this case, we access a value using its key: `data.RecordID`.

Comment: Hi and thank your for your reply. Using your code, when I run the script it returns undefined on the "alert( 'Record ID: ' + data[7] );" If I use console.log to look at what "data" returns I can see the record row I clicked on. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, I am placing the code inside the rowCallback: function(row, data){

Comment: My mistake - sorry about that. I failed to account for the fact that you used `tabletoday` as the variable name for your table: `tabletoday = $('#userTable').DataTable({...}`. I have adjusted the answer to account for this: `var data = tabletoday.row(...)`. Hope that resolves the problem.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd comment - my code needs to be placed _after_ the DataTable configuration code, not anywhere inside it. It is a separate function, which uses the assigned variable name `tabletoday`. I have also adjusted the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be a pain but I am still getting "undefined" as the RecordID. If I view data in the console I see: {RoomName: "Brindley Suite", ClientName: "Bytec", ClientImage: "navex_logo.png", RoomFromDate: "03-08-2020 07:00", RoomToDate: "08-08-2020 18:00", …} ClientImage: "navex_logo.png" ClientName: "Bytec" FullBoardRoom: null Override: "0" RecordID: "53325" RoomFromDate: "03-08-2020 07:00" RoomName: "Brindley Suite" RoomToDate: "08-08-2020 18:00" ToDateTime: 1596909600 WayfinderOnOff: "1" which is what I would expect

Comment: OK - no problem. That data sample helps, thank you. Change my `alert` line to this: `alert( 'Record ID: ' + data.RecordID );`. If that works, I will update my answer with an explanation - otherwise, I am stuck.

Comment: Perfect, works absolutely fine. I was just reading through the datatables documentation when you replied. Many thanks for all your time.